# Audio button works in one modal box but not in another, why?

Tags: jquery, audio, modal-dialog

In one jquery ui modal dialog, I've got a button accessing selected audio files. This is the dialog content setup:

```
    var form_config  ='<div id="t2e_modal"><span id="wrap_user_fb"><img id="user_fb" src="/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/grey32.png" alt="fb" height="20px" width="20px"></span><p id="eng_text">Please enter the English text here</p><p id="thai_text">กรุณาเขียนเป็นภาษาอังกฤษที่นี่</p><form id="t2e_form" action="#"><input type="text" id="t2e_w" name="t2e_w" autocomplete="off"><input id="t2e_submit" type="submit" value="Submit"><p><span class="fa fa-volume-up fa_volume_t2e"></span></p></form><span id="output"></div>';
    /* form config appended to dialog   */
    jQuery("div#t2e_dialog").append(form_config);
```

and this plays the audio:

```
    jQuery("span.fa-volume-up").on("click",function (evnt) {
    var elementId = idClickedEl.replace(/_img/i,""),
      pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML,
      oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg",
      mp3Var = pathVar+elementId+".mp3",
      audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    audioElement.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? oggVar : mp3Var;
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();
});
```

All this works OK, no problem. But in another modal dialog with essentially similar code, the dialog displays OK with selected text in place but the audio does not play. Here is the dialog content:

```
  var ws_modal_html = '<div class = "ws_dialog_box"><p class = "ws_dialog_text">Here is the word (in red) in a sentence</p><p class="ws_dialog_thai">คำในประโยค</p><p class = "ws_dialog_sentence"></p><p><span class="fa fa-volume-up fa_volume_ws"></span></p></div>';
  ws_dlog.html(ws_modal_html);
  jQuery("div.ws_dialog_box p.ws_dialog_sentence").text(modalText);
```

and this is the audio play section:

```
jQuery("span.fa-volume-up").on("click", function(evnt) {     //div#wsd_text
    alert("hello");
    var pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML,
      oggVar = pathVar + "wsde" +  idClickedEl + ".ogg",
      mp3Var = pathVar + "wsde" + idClickedEl + ".mp3",
      audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    audioElement.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? oggVar : mp3Var;
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();
});
```

When the audio button (fa-volume-up) is clicked, the alert("hello") does not display suggesting that the jQuery selection is not working. Something obvious?? Any help would be very welcome. Thanks

Comment: is it possible that you generate this second modal after the page is loaded?

Comment: Both blocks of html create a `.span.fa-volume-up` element and both javascript blocks attach a click handler to `jQuery("span.fa-volume-up")`, therefore (unless there's some black magic to which we are not privy) both click handlers are attached to both elements. I don't know if that's the issue but it certainly doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see all of your code, but if you have that click event AFTER that html is added to the page (so, after the code where you're appending it to the DOM, it should work.

If not, you simply need to make it a delegated event.

```
$('[PARENTSELECTOR]').on('click', '[CHILDSELECTOR]', function () {
    /* click event code here */
});
```

Comment: @Martin Solev, perhaps I didn't make myself clear, the modals are called in different pages (after a page is loaded).

Comment: It works!! $("div#ws_dialog")on("click", "span.fa-volume-up" ..... I was aware of event delegation but not this way of implementing it. Many thanks for your help. Big Green Tick :) Roy

Comment: Anytime Roy. Glad I could help